# Traducción de la etiqueta [burninate-request]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Los que ya sean familiares con la *administración* de etiquetas en enSO Meta conocen la etiqueta [burninate-request](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request), ¿cuál sería una buena traducción para nuestro sitio?

De acuerdo a la descripción del sitio en inglés

> Requests to have a tag "burninated" (or deleted) from the system.

En mi opinión, una traducción sería [solicitud-de-borrado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-borrado)

Comment: ¿`solicitud-de-quemar-con-napalm-mientras-ríes-como-un-maniaco`?

Comment: @ninjalj http://i.imgur.com/oDDoWNg.png ?

Comment: Solicitado en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1731/127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personalmente [solicitud-de-borrado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-borrado) me parece demasiado formal. En la versión en inglés se intenta mantener un espíritu desenfadado en el proceso de borrado de etiquetas porque es un proceso tedioso y aburrido, y es común ver [solicitudes con títulos divertidos y con juegos de palabras](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests).

De hecho, *burninate* es una palabra inventada en Internet (mezcla de *burn* e *incinerate* si no me equivoco) que viene de la serie Homestar Runners, inspirada por el personaje [Trogdor the Burninator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Bad#Trogdor_the_Burninator):

[image: Trogdor the Burninator]

Creo que sería interesante mantener ese espíritu desenfadado de la versión en inglés, buscar alguna palabra (inventada o no) en la misma línea que *burninate* y utilizarla de manera paralela.

Quizás podríamos buscar inspiración en alguna serie que haya influido en nuestra comunidad o en la sociedad en general, por ejemplo Bola de Dragón, el Chapulín Colorado, o el Cálico Electrónico (por mencionar algunas).

Y si eligieramos una palabra relacionada con el fuego, quemar o tostar cosas (¿[solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado)?¿[solicitud-de-requemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-requemado)?, lo siento no soy muy original) siempre podríamos mantener a Trogdor como mascota :)

Comment: Por lo comentado, yo optaría por adoptar la etiqueta "solicitud-de-quemado".

Comment: El caso de *burninated* es tan viral que en realidad es un [meme del meta de SO en inglés](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/137182). No tiene mucho sentido traducirlo de esa manera ya que jamás tendría el mismo sentido para la mayoría de usuarios. Lo que si se podría hacer es escoger otra palabra o frase que tenga significado para la comunidad de habla hispana, que no sea una traducción literal

Comment: Y no recomiendo algún ataque de Dragon Ball o Bola de Dragón porque ya mi imagino las peleas sobre cual de las versiones se debe usar

Comment: ¿Y qué tal las palabras del Chapulín; "¡Chanfle! ¡Rechanfle! ¡Recontrachanfle!"? Quizás algo como [tag:chanflear-etiqueta] o [tag:solicitud-de-rechanfle]

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Ya veo venir las peleas sobre "Kame hame ha" y "Onda vital" :P