# Hacer [burninate-request] sinónimo de [solicitud-de-quemado]

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

Poco a poco van surgiendo las solicitudes de quemados. Hoy día contamos con preguntas en Meta con una o dos de las siguientes etiquetas que significan lo mismo:

- [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)
- [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado)

Dado que este es un sitio en español, la etiqueta principal debería ser [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) y tener como sinónimo [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

Comment: Sugerido en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/solicitud-de-quemado/synonyms <-- 2 clicks para un ♦

Comment: @Mariano entendí que no es [meta-tag:soporte] porque no pide cómo funciona algo, sino [meta-tag:característica-nueva] porque solicita que algo se implemente. De ahí el cambio de etiqueta.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo entiendo que característica-nueva es para características nuevas las cuales implican modificar el código o configuración por parte de un empleado, no por la comunidad/moderadores diamantados.

Comment: @Rubén recuerdo que un día debatimos al respecto y sigo pensando que [la ayuda de Meta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) tampoco clarifica mucho: _[support], que indica que es una solicitud de asistencia o soporte con alguna de las funciones del sitio._, _[feature-request], para proponer una nueva función para el sitio, o solicitar que alguna función actual sea modificada_. Para mí la descripción de [meta-tag:soporte] es "cómo se usa algo" y no "por favor, cambiad esto". Pero lo mismo soy yo que lo interpreto así :)

Comment: @Mariano viendo [cómo definisteis la etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/733/revisions), sí, tienes razón. No habia leído su descripción. Elimino esta etiqueta

Comment: @Mariano en cuanto a [meta-tag:soporte] veo que a Rubén [le contestaron en Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291271/209901): _TL;DR: [support] is for questions that want facts in their answers, whereas [discussion] is for questions that want opinions in their answers_. Iría entonces más en el sentido que yo uso.

Comment: @fedorqui Entiendo, y me convenciste que no es [meta-tag:soporte]... En cuanto a la descripción de [meta-tag:traducciones], fue en base a las preguntas que estaban etiquetadas así... Por supuesto que siempre podemos cambiar el significado (no lo defino sólo yo), pero me parece una buena idea poder agrupar todo lo de la interfaz en una etiqueta exclusiva.

Comment: @Mariano me parece perfecto como lo definisteis. Me quedé pensando en qué otra se podría utililzar para estos menesteres. ¿[meta-tag:idiomas] tal vez?

Comment: @fedorqui en cuanto a [meta-tag:soporte] me habías convencido, pero mirá en MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonym-request/info (Rubén me comentó sobre esa info)

Comment: @Mariano interesante, pues fue un CM quien [añadió este bloque](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/97836/revisions) (en base a algo que alguien [decidió en 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/62919/revisions)). La verdad es que viendo la descripción de ambas etiquetas no queda nada claro y las dos podrían justificarse ([support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info) y [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) en SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado la sugerencia de @Mariano, ahora son sinónimos.

> [solicitud-de-quemado](/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado) (etiqueta maestra) - [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)